# How to parse json arrays into array rather than object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have following foobar variable which is string(I get it like so by querying a webserver with $http.post):

```
var foobar = "[{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}]";
```

How do I make an array out of that? If I use JSON.parse, it will provide me with an object(tried `typeof foobar`). But, if I then use `delete param1`, it will then make it [null, {param2: 'value2'}]. What I want to do, basically is to remove first or second item. Also, value may be different, but keys will always stay the same, ie. they'll be numbers.

Comment: I don't understand your question - the variable `foobar` _is_ an array, with two elements that are each objects.  Your `delete param1` can't even work because that's a key of the 0th _inner object_.

Comment: did you mean `var foobar = "[{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}]";`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to wrap it under double-quotes,

Comment: And now it's not a valid JSON.

Comment: @zerkms What do you mean? I get that, as I said, from the webserver, and when I do `type of` that particular part of the response, it says string.

Comment: It is a string, but it's not a valid JSON. Check it using any JSON validator. (eg http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Given I'd need to pick on webdev working on the way data is sent back, is there a way to do what I want to do?

Comment: @Milos given your format is broken - any chance you fix it first?

Comment: @zerkms I can, but that would involve waiting for developer working on APIs, which I'd rather skip.

Comment: @Milos well, it really makes very little sense to not fix it first.

Comment: You've been of tremendous help, thanks. ;)

Comment: `typeof [] === 'object'` running typeof on any array will always say it is an object, use [].isArray instead

Comment: @zerkms jslint json validator says "[{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}]" is valid json.

Comment: @Milos quotes around are not part of JSON, but a JS string literal. Validate the `[{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}]`

Comment: @JarodMoser Let's say I have an object, and one of the params has the value of "[{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}]". I did typeof on that parameter, and got string.

Comment: that would be because `"[{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}]"` *is* a string...

Comment: I just checked: When I get that data, it's an array, but as I need to store it into sessionStorage, I needed to `JSON.stringify()` it. Now, when I need it to be an array again, I can't make it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're wanting to parse your array into a single object, from your delete statement.  If so...

```js
var foobar = '[{"param1":"value1"},{"param2":"value2"}]';
var json = JSON.parse(foobar);

json = json.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
  Object.keys(currentValue).forEach(function(key){
    previousValue[key] = currentValue[key];
  });
  return previousValue;
}, {});

console.log(json);
```

I could be wrong though.

Comment: `json.reduce((a, o) => Object.assign(a, o), {})` :-)

Comment: Ohh, fancy. :D  Ya, i'm not up on ES6 fully yet.

Comment: Btw, also note that OP has a broken JSON and apparently they are not willing to fix it. So presumably `JSON.parse` would not work.

Comment: Lol, well.  *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

### Description

This is already an array `var foobar = [{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}];`.

### Example

```js
var foobar = [{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}];
// this is an array
console.log(foobar);
// this is an object in an array
console.log(foobar[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var foobar = [{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}];
```

is an array.

```js
var foobar = [{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}];
console.log(foobar instanceof Array)
```

If you want to remove the first item you can just use the `shift` method:

```js
var foobar = [{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}];
foobar.shift();
console.log(foobar)
```

While if you want to remove the second item you can use the `pop` method:

```js
var foobar = [{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}];
foobar.pop();
console.log(foobar)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others say, what you are providing is already an array.

```
var foobar = [{param1: 'value1'}, {param2: 'value2'}];
//You can see this because of the []
//You can delete the index of an array by using the splice method
foobar.splice(1,1);
//First param is the index, the second is the number of items to erase
```

Answer (score 0):

What's probably confusing you the most is `typeof`.

In the case of arrays, `typeof` will say it is an object ([as you can read from MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)). If you want to test to see if a variable is an array, you could use: `foobar.isArray()`